# Creating References to Objects

Tags: java, object, reference

I have this Object here:

```
public class ItemInfo {

    String productName;
    String rfidTagNumber;
    String originalLocal;
    String currentLocal;
    double productPrice;

    public ItemInfo(String name, String tag, String origLoc, String curLoc, double price) {
        productName = name;
        rfidTagNumber = tag;
        originalLocal = origLoc;
        currentLocal = curLoc;
        productPrice = price;
    }
```

I need to create and have a reference to an `ItemInfo` Object in here:

```
public class ItemInfoNode {

    ItemInfoNode next;
    ItemInfoNode prev;

    public ItemInfoNode(){

    }

    public void setInfo(ItemInfo info) {

    }

    public ItemInfo getInfo(){
        return null;    
    }

    public void setNext(ItemInfoNode node) {

    }

    public void setPrev(ItemInfoNode node) {

    }

    public ItemInfoNode getNext() {
        return null;
    }

    public ItemInfoNode getPrev() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I know how to make new objects but I am not quite sure that is correct so I omitted the line, how do I create just a reference?

EDIT: Just another small sidebar, I have two ItemInfoNode objects next and prev as seen above, do I just leave the constructor blank? Is that okay? I pasted the rest of the class to show functions, if that'll help an answer in anyway. Thanks again!

Comment: What do you mean by creating just a reference? you can make a new instance of ItemInfo in ItemInfoNode by `ItemInfo objItemInfo = new ItemInfo("Test name", "tag", "loc", "loc", 0.0);`

Comment: Yeah I am not sure what is required of me, my description simply says "...contains a reference to an ItemInfo object..." refering to this ItemInfoNode class, I don't get why I don't just make an object.

Comment: I guess you will have to first generate ItemInfo object and then assign a variable to it to make it reference. Unless you get ItemInfo from elsewhere, I suppose you will have to generate one within the ItemInfoNode class.

Answer (score 6):

In Java, the `new` keyword returns a reference to a newly-constructed object. Therefore, in

```
String s = new String("foo");
```

the value of variable `s` is a reference to a String object. And then, if you were to do something like

```
String t = s;
```

then you've set `t` to the same value as `s`, which is to say, it's now a reference to the same object.

Comment: Note that this is only an example. In most cases you should avoid using new String.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you are trying to accomplish but the simplest way to create an object is to the use the class name `ItemInfo` and the `new` keyword. For example, you could this line of code and declare your object reference globally:

```
ItemInfo myObj= new ItemInfo();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a new instance like this

`ItemInfo myObj = new ItemInfo("name", "tag", "location", "local", 0.0);`

Or, do something like this:-

```
public class ItemInfoNode{

        ItemInfo myObj;

        public ItemInfoNode(ItemInfo myObj){

        this.myObj = myObj;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an implementation of a [LinkedList](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). So what you want to do is to store the reference to the next node and previous ItemInfoNode using the setters - i.e. setNext() and setPrev() method by storing the arguments (which are the references) as your class variables next and prev which you declared already. Then in your getters - i.e. getPrev() and getNext() you can return your stored variables.

```
public void setNext(ItemInfoNode node){
    next = node;
}
public void setPrev(ItemInfoNode node){
    prev = node;
}
public ItemInfoNode getNext(){
    return next;
}
public ItemInfoNode getPrev(){
    return prev;
}
```